# Listview occur error when scrolling down

Tags: android, listview, scroll

When I am scrolling down to the bottom of the list it throws an error but if not scrolling everything works correctly, please help me. Here is my code:

customadapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context c;
String[] players;
int[] images;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] players, int[] images) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowmodel, players);

    this.c = context;
    this.players = players;
    this.images = images;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView nameTv;
    ImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowmodel, null);
    }

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.nameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        holder.nameTv.setText(players[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] players={" Ronaldo"," Modric"," Marcelo","Amanda","ola","andrea","girl"};
int[]images={R.drawable.ronaldo,R.drawable.modric,R.drawable.marcelo,R.drawable.amanda,R.drawable.ola,R.drawable.andrea,R.drawable.girl};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,players,images);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Toast.makeText(this,l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

MainActivity.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFF0EEEE"
    tools:context="com.example.qais.lastchance.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

rowmodel.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listshape">


    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Cristiano Ronaldo"
        android:id="@+id/nameTv"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"

        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the error

```
04-25 18:07:10.911 1781-1781/com.example.qais.lastchance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.qais.lastchance, PID: 1781
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 423360012 byte allocation with 11587572 free bytes and 111MB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:837)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:656)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1037)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4037)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3910)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1982)
   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:409)
   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:758)
   at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:409)
   at com.example.qais.lastchance.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:52)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2826)
   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1932)
   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:751)
   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1727)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2624)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2483)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2185)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7062)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: You are not using viewholder pattern correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Out of Memory exception, your images (drawables you try to load into your image views) are too large.

Answer (score 0):

As advice [recycleView](http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example) this will make u use smaller amount of memory due to the view holders patterns .
and for your images use `Picasso` library to make image loading smoother and to handle caching

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context c;
    String[] players;
    int[] images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] players, int[] images) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowmodel, players);
      inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.c = context;
        this.players = players;
        this.images = images;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView nameTv;
        ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           ViewHolder holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null){      
               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowmodel, null);
               // well set up the ViewHolder
               holder = new ViewHolder();        
               holder.nameTv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
               holder.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
               // store the holder with the view.
               v.setTag(holder);        
           }
           else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
           }


            holder.nameTv.setText(players[position]);
            holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return v;
    }
```